# Javascript: How to create a function in an object when the name is stored in a variable

Tags: javascript

I have the need to create a function from a name stored in a variable. Usually this is pretty simple, I've done it before using:

```
  var funcName = "theName";
  window[funcName] = function(){
    // code here
  };
```

However in my new usecase the function I create needs to sit inside an object called `the.Name`.  So what I tried to do, and it doesn't work is:

```
  var funcName = "the.Name";
  window[funcName] = function(){
    // code here
  };
```

The reason it doesn't work is because I can't reference `window["the.Name"]` as that's invalid, the correct way is `window["the"]["Name"]`.

Does anyone have a a solution for this problem? Basically naming a function which will sit inside an object when the name is stored in a variable.

Comment: Does the `the` object exist already, or are you creating that object dynamically as well?

Comment: @Brandan Sorry I should of mentioned. An object called "the" already exists. However the.Name does not.

Comment: Just tested myself and it doesn't work. But getting some good answers anyway.

Answer (score 2):

OK, I seem to understand your problem.

Here's some code to get you started.

```
/**
 * @param fn The function to bind.
 * @param path The object to bind to.
 * @param root The root object.
 */
function bindFunc(fn, path, root){
    path = path.split('.');
    var base = root;
    for(var i=0; i<path.length-1; i++){
        base = base[path[i]];
    }
    base[path[path.length - 1]] = fn;
}

bindFunc(function(){  }, 'the.Name', window);
```

Comment: this is how `jQuery.extend` and `YAHOO.namespace` (from yui2) work internally

Comment: shouldn't it be `base = base[path[i]]` instead of `base = base[path[1]]` ?

Comment: @Kirean there is no such functionality in jQuery

Comment: @CD.. Ah, for a minute I thought you were talking about the last line in the function! My apologies, you were entirely correct -  my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to make a guess that you're trying to do something "namespace-like". Here's an article that should get you started (has some good example code, too)..

http://blogger.ziesemer.com/2008/05/javascript-namespace-function.html

Comment: +1, but here is slightly better implementation of it: http://addyosmani.com/blog/essential-js-namespacing/

Answer (score 1):

If you're sure that all object till the last one exists (the last one could also not be defined), the shortest way probably is using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```
var func = funcName.split(".").reduce(function(p, c) {
    return p[c];
}, window);
```

Comment: **if** you are sure ;) in practice this will break quite often, but the piece of code is quite elegant. +1 for creative use of `reduce`.

Answer (score 0):

Split the string so that you can reference one level at a time:

```
var names = funcname.split(".");
var f = window;
for (var i = 0; i < names.length - 1; i++) {
  f = f[names[i]];
}
f[names[names.length - 1]] = function(){...};
```